# Usando a página raiz

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Meus caros amigos que usam Angular, terminei o curso de Angular 9 da cod3r recentemente e agora estou praticando bastante. Coloquei um component login e queria saber se ele deveria ser a página raiz ou layout do site que deveria?
Eu estava definindo o login como página raiz porém eu estava com muita trabalhera de fixar os components que tem o conteúdo entre 3 components ( header,footer e nav). E no curso quando estava fazendo somente com a página raiz e utilizando o mat-side-nav-content pra aparecer os conteúdos eles estavam fixando entre os negócios bonitinho. Agora vi um jeito aq no chatgpt de colocar pra quando entrar na raiz ser direcionado para  o component login e depois voltar pro layout do site. Queria saber se vou ter problema futuramente se eu quiser expandir mais ainda o projeto utilizando esse direcionamento da página raiz?
Ou se vocês me ajudarem a fixar o conteúdo agradeço tbm kkk

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Você não terá problemas. Aconselho você a desenvolver uma pagina splashscreen que é responsavel por validar se o usuario esta logado, caso esteja logado redirecione o usuario para o conteúdo do seu projeto, caso não esteja logado redireciona para a pagina de login.

**obs:**  uma animação e um tempo minimo pra essa validação da um ar muito profissional e bonito para a splashScreen

app-routing.module.ts

```
  [...]

  const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: SplashScreenComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'main',
      loadChildren: () =>
        import('./navigation/navigation.module').then(
          m => m.NavigationModule,
        ),
    },
    {
      path: 'auth',
      component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
      path: '**',
      component: NotFoundComponent,
    }
  ];

  @NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
  })
  export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**obs 2:** vou deixar um exeemplo de animação para a splash que gosto muito de usar:

splash-screen.component.html

```
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <section >
        <img src="/assets/images/Sìmbolo-rosa.png" class="bluebag" width="200">
      </section>
    </header>
  </div>
```

splash-screen.component.scss

```
   .bluebag {
      animation-name: effectSplashScreen;
      animation-duration: 1500ms;
      animation-delay: 0s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: 10000;
    }
    @keyframes effectSplashScreen {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 0.5;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
```